# set MySqlParameter = -1 if null

Tags: c#, parameters, nullable

I am trying to use SQL queries, but I meet a problem with nullable objects :

Here is my code where I define all MySql parameters :

```
MySqlParameter[] listParams = new MySqlParameter[]
{
    new MySqlParameter("id", this.ID),
    new MySqlParameter("idStock", this.idStock),
    new MySqlParameter("certificate", this.certificate),
    new MySqlParameter("idLO", this.launchingOrder.ID),
    new MySqlParameter("idToleOri", this.toleOri.ID),
    new MySqlParameter("idTolesOri", string.Join("+", this.idTolesOri)),
    new MySqlParameter("listInstructions", string.Join("|", this.listInstructions)),
    new MySqlParameter("length", this.length),
    new MySqlParameter("width", this.width),
};
```

In my case, `this.toleOri` can be null. I would like to say if toleOri == null, then param.Value = -1.
But when I execute the query, VS gives an error on the line `new MySqlParameter("idToleOri", this.toleOri.ID)`. (because toleOri is null)

How is it possible to solve that? The only way I found is to always initialize `tleOri` with ID=-1.
I also tried `(this.toleOri.ID ?? -1)`, but then it says that `??` cannot be used for int or doubles. I understand the message, but don't see how to solve it?

Comment: Have you tried to assign using logical operators? i.e. `this.toleOri == null ? -1 : this.toleOri.ID`

Comment: @chungonion no in fact, I don't know well that syntax, but it seems to work. Thanks (may you post as answer, or may I delete question?)

Comment: *"I would like to say if toleOri == null, then param.Value = -1"*. So say that. The suggested solution is more succinct but what was stopping you writing a regular `if` statement for yourself?

Comment: That particular constructor is the same as using `AddWithValue`, which is not recommended. You should always explicitly state the type of each parameter.

Comment: @John first, because I was trying to make it fit in one line. Then I don't see how I could put some else/if on the right side? I believed I just can put a value? Will try it, even if chungonion's answer is more succinct as you say, then I also will learn how to better use that `??` think

Comment: Posted as answer anyway, hope that helps!

Comment: @John `You should always explicitly state the type of each parameter.` I don't understand? In my SQL database, I save the `listOri` ID (-1 if null).

Comment: Nowhere in your question does it say that you want to do it in one line or that you had already done it in more than one line. What you should have been able to do was do it in more than one line and then ask how to implement that same logic in a single line. You should ALWAYS do all you can for yourself first and then ask as little of us as possible.

Comment: *"I don't understand"*. Where are you specifying the type of each parameter? You're not. You're relying on the type being inferred from the value you provide. If you do that then the wrong type may be inferred. If you take the time to look at the available constructors then you'll see that there are several and most of them allow you to specify the type.

Comment: @John I guess I may look further about parametrization, I believed one of the advantage was that the type was inferred. I looked at constructor but I don't see any constructr that has both `type` and `value`? what would you suggest then? make everytime something like that `new MySqlParameter("id",MySqlDbType.Int64){Value=this.id }`?

Comment: That is correct. Most examples will add a parameter directly to a `Parameters` collection and you'll find that they call `Add` and then set the `Value` property on the returned object. What you showed would be the equivalent in your scenario. I think most people here refer to [this](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) on the subject and it has such an example.

Comment: @John I read your article, but the example `cmd.Parameters.Add("@Parameter", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = MyDateTimeVariable;` is not working, would be fine to keep my structure, replacing by something like `new MySqlParameter("id",MySqlDbType.Int64){Value=this.id }` you think?

Comment: It's an example, demonstrating a principle. You need to apply that principle to your specific scenario. We've gone beyond the scope of this question so I'll comment no more here. If you have a new question on a different topic, you should post that separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try to use `this.toleOri == null ? -1 : this.toleOri.ID`, then it will assign `-1` when this.toleOri is null, and get the `ID` value of `this.toleOri` when it is not null.

Comment: Assuming a fairly recent version of C#, it would be more succinct to use `this.toleOri?.ID ?? -1`.